# what's wrong with the script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

can figure out what's wrong? always returns failure

```
function addItem() {
            var rowCount = $('#grid').getGridParam('records');
            var lastRow = $('#grid').getRowData(rowCount - 1);

            var newRow = lastRow;
            newRow.Id = "0";
            newRow.Person = "";
            newRow.Date = "";

            var newItem = $('grid').addRowData(rowCount - 1, newRow);

            if (newItem == true) {
                alert('success');
            }
            else { alert('falire'); }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know, but perhaps this:

```
var newItem = $('grid').addRowData(rowCount - 1, newRow);
```

Should be this:

```
var newItem = $('#grid').addRowData(rowCount - 1, newRow); // missing pound sign
```

-- edit:

And if this turns out to be the problem, I suggest you define the names of things at the top, like so:

```
var theGridElement = $("#grid");
```

Thus helping in these little mistakes of minor inconsistency :)

Comment: almost certainly.  The former would be trying to match <grid> html elements, not html elements with id "grid"